# OpenLayers WFS no FID being passed from TinyOWS

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, wfs-t, tinyows

I have a webapp - OpenLayers<->tinyows<->postgis. With 1 layer I have a problem.

On localhost all works well - here is a snip of the XML I get back:

```
 <gml:featureMember>
   <tows:trad gml:id="trad.34">
   <tows:geom><gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326"><gml:pos>12.01865 57.666245</gml:pos></gml:Point></tows:geom>
   etc...
```

but on my web server, the XML I get back is:

```
 <gml:featureMember>
   <tows:trad>
   <tows:ogc_fid>34</tows:ogc_fid>
   <tows:geom><gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326"><gml:pos>12.01865   57.666245</gml:pos></gml:Point></tows:geom>
   etc...
```

The layer displays fine, but this quirk means that I am unable to edit the layer:

tinyows error:
    [Tue Mar 18 16:33:07 2014] [ERROR] Element '{http://www.opengis.net/ogc}FeatureId': The attribute 'fid' is required but missing.

/etc/tinyows.xml:

```
<tinyows online_resource="http://localhost/cgi-bin/tinyows"
     schema_dir="/usr/share/tinyows/schema/"
     log="/var/log/tinyows.log"
     log_level="15" >

<pg host="localhost" user="postgres" password="xxxx" dbname="test" port="5432"/>

<metadata name="TinyOWS Server"
       title="treeMapp TinyOWS Server - Service" />

<layer retrievable="1"
    writable="1"
    ns_prefix="tows"
    ns_uri="http://www.tinyows.org/"
    name="trad"
    table="trad"
    title="Träd" />

<layer retrievable="1"
    writable="1"
    ns_prefix="tows"
    ns_uri="http://www.tinyows.org/"
    name="tradtest"
    table="tradtest"
    title="Träd test" />

</tinyows>
```

Other layers on the same set up on the web server work fine.

Comment: Check if the table in the webserver have the same definition (check if it has a primary key defined)

Comment: Yep - the table's a copy of the localhost, has a primary key on ogc_fid which is a sequence, the table was created with ogr2ogr.

Comment: Just edited - added /etc/tinyows.xml

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the 2 xml have a different version of the GML:

This seems GMLv3.1

```
<gml:featureMember>
   <tows:trad gml:id="trad.34">  <!-- gml:id -->
   <tows:geom><gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326"><gml:pos>12.01865 57.666245</gml:pos>        </gml:Point></tows:geom>
   etc...
```

This seems GMLv2

```
<gml:featureMember>
   <tows:trad>
   <tows:ogc_fid>34</tows:ogc_fid>
   <tows:geom><gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326"><gml:pos>12.01865   57.666245</gml:pos>    </gml:Point></tows:geom>
   etc...
```

Maybe the two server have different versions? The last xml-snippet suggest that the server is not able to recognize the primary key for the layer